# java downcasting constructor call?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have Class Parent and Class Child sharing inheritance relationship. The child class has parameterised constructor. While downcasting the parent class to child class, will the child constructor be called?

Comment: at the point where you downcast it, the object instance should already exist and the child constructor is already invoked. So i don´t understand the question here.

Comment: I don´t know If I understand the question, but I think you are asking about cast an element to a parametrize type.
yes, you can: 

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Object obj = (Object) arr;
        
        ArrayList<String> arr2 = (ArrayList<String>) arr;

Comment: i mean there is some logic by subclass constructor has to assign data to one of its paramater. since i am not calling constructor of subclass and just downcasting it... Will the logic present in side child class construct will execute or not?

Answer (score 1):

No. Casting is independent of construction.  The constructor for class X returns an instance of class X.  If you have

```
class X { ... }
class Y extends X { ... }
X my_x = new X();
Y my_y = (Y)  my_x; <=== ClassCastExceptoin
```

This will throw an exception. The following would work:

```
class X { ... }
class Y extends X { ... }
X my_x = new Y();     // Note subclass constructor call
Y my_y = (Y)  my_x;   // my_x really referred to a Y instance, so this is OK
```

Comment: So if there are some parameters that are being assigned through constructor, will not get assigned using downcasting?